# ASP.NET Guardar archivo dentro un carpeta

Tags: c#, asp.net, microsoft-office, mvp

Hola amigos estoy tratando de guardar un archivo dentro de un carpeta que creo de forma dinámica, hasta aquí no hay problema, la cuestión es que cuando le intento pasar el **file** ya en mi método lo recibe como **Null**, ¿alguien podría decirme en donde estoy errando?
 Estoy obteniendo este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
    [HttpPost]        
    public void  CreateFolder() {

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {

            foreach (HttpPostedFile file in Request.Files)
            {

                Random rnd = new Random();

                int rndx = rnd.Next(0, 1000);

                string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
                
                
                var folder = Server.MapPath("~/Facturas/" + rndx);
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Facturas/" + rndx)
                    , "" + rndx + "_" + dt + "_" + fname + "_" + extension);
                    file.SaveAs(filePath);
                }
            }

       

        }
    //end method
    }
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFolder", "SAMAcceso", FormMethod.Post)) { @Html.TextBox("file","",new {type= "file" })
<input type="submit" value="cargar" /> }
```

Comment: probaste obteniendo el archivo con `Request.Files`?

Comment: pues no pero el null me lo da desde (HttpPostedFile file) donde file es null

Comment: Te lo comento porque realice una prueba de tu código y usando eso no tengo problema; crea una variable y almacena `Request.Files` en ella, hazle un _debug_ y nos comentas que te trae :)

Comment: sobres ya ando en ello pero mi compu anda lenta hoy D:

Comment: Tengo tiempo amigo, nos comentas como te va con eso :D

Comment: Sigo en NULL, podrías postear como lo tienes tú ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues esto terminé haciendo, por si alguien le sirve

```js
[HttpPost]
public void CreateFolder() {

  if (Request.Files.Count > 0) {

    var file = Request.Files[0];
    Random rnd = new Random();

    int rndx = rnd.Next(0, 1000);

    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");

    var folder = Server.MapPath("~/Facturas/" + rndx);
    if (!Directory.Exists(folder)) {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
      string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Facturas/" + rndx), rndx + "_" + "_" + "_" + extension);
      file.SaveAs(filePath);
    }




  }
  //end method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el *form* debes agregar el atributo `multipart/form-data` de la siguiente forma

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateFolder", "SAMAcceso", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })
    <input type="submit" value="cargar" /> 
}
```

El parámetro **HttpPostedFile file** deberías quitarlo y obtener el archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
public void CreateFolder()
{
   if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
   {
      foreach(string filename in Request.Files)
      {
         HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[filename];
      }
   }
}
```

El `foreach` lo utilizarías exclusivamente si tu método recibirá **múltiples archivos**, de lo contrario bastaría con un `Request.Files[0]`.

Con eso bastaría, nos comental que tal

Comment: Pues más o menos, pero ahora no puedo accesar a las propiedades de mi File, como su nombre y esas cosas ... sabes como obtener esto? con un for quizá?

Comment: Edito la respuesta, aunque tu mismo tienes la solución ;)

Comment: modifiqué todo ya actualizé pero sigo con un error

Comment: Te recomiendo que cierres esta pregunta, ya que se solucionó lo que originalmente querías y crees otra con el nuevo error amigo, de este modo evitamos que haya tanta confusión, si te fijas el encabezado de la pregunta que hiciste es el mismo pero cambiaste el código. Cuando la hayas cerrado, no tengo problema en ayudarte con el error :D